# When player falls while parkouring he gets teleported to certain coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I make it that when a certain player activates this command `/execute if entity @a[x=257,y=69,z=-175,dx=11,dz=4] run teleport @p 260 74 -177`, he gets teleported but not the other players nearby?

I'm trying to make if the player falls off while parkouring he gets teleported back to the coordinates: `260 74 -177`. I don't want to make it so that the player gets killed when he falls I just want him to get teleported to those coordinates.

Because this command teleports the player that is the closest to the command block. I want the command block to teleport the player that executes the command `/execute if entity @a[x=257,y=69,z=-175,dx=11,dz=4]`.

Comment: I'm making this for multiplayer, Minecraft version 1.6.4.

Comment: Whoops I meant 1.16.4. Sorry.

Comment: 1.6.4 was realesed like, back in 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/execute as @a[x=257,y=69,z=-175,dx=11,dz=4] run teleport @s 260 74 -177
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it

Comment: @Karolis If this solved your problem please use the check button on the left to mark your problem as solved.